# $scope not updating unless called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

Please see my codes below. I am having a hard time showing the value of $scope.brand in my view. When I click the *get user brand button* nothing happens. The brand.name in the view didn't updated but when I click the *test brand button* after I clicked the *get user brand button*, the value of the scope will show. I don't know what's happening now. Please help. Thank you!

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('nwApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

var url = 'http://localhost:3000';

app.controller('brandsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

$scope.brands = {};
$scope.brand = {};

$http.get(url+'/brands/all')
    .success(function(result){
        $scope.brands = result;
    });

    $scope.getAssignUser = function(brand_id){
        $.get(url+'/brands/'+brand_id)
            .success(function(result){
                $scope.brand = result;
            });

        $("#brandModal").modal('toggle');
    };

    $scope.checkBrand = function(){
        console.log($scope.brand);
    }
}]);
```

**View**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-warning" title="Assign User for this Brand" ng-click='getAssignUser(brand._id)' >GET USER BRAND</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-warning"  ng-click='checkBrand()' > TEST BRAND </a>

<div><% brand.name %></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 $.get(url+'/brands/'+brand_id)
            .success(function(result){
                $scope.brand = result;
            });
```

`$.get` is jquery so when it updates the $scope.brand in the success the digest cycle will not run and reflect the value.

You should make use of the `$http` service provided by angular for doing ajax:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: url+'/brands/'+brand_id
}).then(function successCallback(result) {
     $scope.brand = result;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

**Other solution is:**

In your jquery ajax you change the scope variable inside `$apply` like this:

```
 $.get(url+'/brands/'+brand_id)
            .success(function(result){
                $scope.$apply(function (){$scope.brand = result;});
            });
```

Comment: WOOOH!! After all this time. Thanks Cyril! It now works!

Comment: And please avoid using $scope until explicitly required. For conteoller to view mapping you can use controllerAs syntax which is better and allows better readability of code and one less dependency in your controller.

Moreover, we have concepts of services in angularjs for all these http calls and other business logic. Please try to keep controllers as light as possible. 

Hope this be of some help